# linter to warn about non-deterministic behaviour

Tags: go, binary-reproducibility

Is there a linter/helper which warns about non-deterministic behaviour in Go programs?  My aim is to have reproducible output in a tool used for reproducible builds.  I would like the linter to warn about use of random number generators, use of `time.Now()`, loops which iterate over maps and select statements, *etc.*

Comment: note that the go compiler already supports binary-reproducibility, that is generating the exact same output file (binary) if the same source code is provided. But that is not strictly related to Determinism

Comment: @Cookie04 Yes, I agree.  My aim is to get the same property for my own program, which is written in Go.

Comment: I have never heard of a linter that does something like this. Isn't it easier in this case to mock the output writer of your command(so it can write to a bytes.buffer instead of os.Stdout), run your command a few times in a test and make sure the output is always the same? This catches most of the issues you describe(accept when using dates which I guess you will not be using in your output on purpose)

Comment: @caveman Yes, that's what I did.  But it would be nice to have some reassurance that I caught "all" of the problems, rather than "most".

Comment: Note that some actions (e.g. rangeing over a map or select) operate non-deterministic by _design_. If you need deterministic behavior Go is the wrong language.